# Exclude section in page from IntelliJ code formatting

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, code-formatting

Is there any possible way to have IntelliJ -not- format part of a page?

I'm using XHTML and facelets but this could apply to any page.  I'm also curious if it's possible to do that in code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since IDEA 13 it is possible to suppress formatting with

```
@formatter:off
```

and reactivate with

```
 @formatter:on
```

inside comments.

But you need to enable that first in Settings -> Code Style -> General -> Formatter Control

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not possible with IntelliJ 9.